# NGINX tcp stream on port 443

Tags: nginx, tcp

Is it possible to have nginx host a website on standard ports 80 and 443 while at the same time having it proxy a tcp stream on the same port 443 ?

In which case, how does nginx know when to route the client to the website and when to route to the stream ? It seems like tcp streams don't support the "server_name" value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to use both stream and http on one port. HTTP has the concept of routing based on server name while a tcp stream cannot route based on a server name.